# Comparing character and String

Tags: java, string

I am writing a program to check wether the given sentence is a panagram or not, but I am not able to compare each character with the characters in a string.
Can anyone suggest me a method to get the desired output?

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String panagram = scan.nextLine();
    String word = panagram.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(word);
    String a[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
            "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
            "x", "y", "z" };
    int count = 1;
    System.out.println("a=" + a.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {

            if ((a[i]).equals(word.charAt(j)))// problem occurs here  {

                count++;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    if (count == 26) {
        System.out.println("pangram");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not pangram");
    }
```

Comment: Use `char[]` instead of `String[]`.

Comment: @kevin I already tried using == but it gives error

Comment: @vineethPrabhakaran nevermind i read your `String[]` as `char[]` somehow

Comment: You could do with a better approach. Add any character which is an alphabet from the sentence ( usually `O(n)` for n characters) to a set and then check size of the Set.  Note that `if` condition to check if element being added is a char is `O(1)`

Comment: Side note (related to TheLostMind's comment): I'm not sure your algorithm works. Consider a string of 26 a's: in the first iteration of the outer loop you get `a[0] = "a"`. Now you loop over the string of 26 'a' characters and call `count++` for each iteration of the inner loop. In the end `count` will be 26 and your code assumes this to be a pangram (although it is not). Besides that it wouldn't work for strings longer than 26 characters. So better use the set approach that TheLostMind suggested.

Comment: @vineethPrabhakaran the reason beeing why it can never find and equal is because the `String#equals` method will allways return `false` if `obj instanceof String == false`, with object beeing `word.charAt(j)`. since `obj` is a `Char` you will never be able compare a `String` to another `Object` which does not represent a `String`

Comment: Slight un-optimal change to the code  `if ((a[i]).equals(word.charAt(j))` to ` if ((a[i]).equals("" + word.charAt(j))` gives you an equality check between strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
(a[i]).equals(String.valueOf(word.charAt(j)))
```

or change your `a` array from `String[]` to `char[]` and compare the character using the `==` operator.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert it to a String and then compare it.

```
String s = Character.toString('c');
if(s.equals(s2)){..}
```

Or you could make it a String by adding it to an empty string.

```
String s = 'c' + "";
if(s.equals(s2)){..}
```

Or you could compare it's ascii value.

As there are only single characters, why don't you use a character array.

```
char []a = {'a', 'b', 'c'....};
if(a[i] == 'a')//you could use == in this case.
{..}
```

---

Also you don't need to check it that way.

You could create a boolean array of 26 size, as there are only 26 characters and check if every character is present atleast once or not

```
boolean []arr = new boolean[26];
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
{
  arr[word.charAt(i) - 'a'] = true;
}
isPan(arr);
public boolean isPan(boolean[] arr)
{
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
 if(!arr[i])
   return false;
return true;
}
```

A simple O(n) solution.

Or you could use a Set and check it's size.

```
HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet();
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i)
  set.add(word.charAt(i));
System.out.println(set.size() == 26 ? "Pangram" : "Not Pangram");

//A 2 liner would be
HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray()));
System.out.println(set.size() == 26 ? "Pangram" : "Not Pangram");
```

---

A point added by spookieCookie. These approaches apply only when the string has only lower case alphabets.

```
String s = "sdgosdgoih3208ABDDu23pouqwpofjew@#$%^&".repalceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
String s = s.toLowerCase();
//do the computation then
```

Comment: The `Set` idea is very clean.

Comment: How about pangram that includes not only characters from alphabet? Add a yourstring.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "") to remove everything from a string except characters. And also should do yourstring.toLowerCase() before doing a set from it's characters.

Comment: @Spookiecookie True, the set approach would fail in that case. But generally pangram checking is done only for lower latin alphabets.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the array into an arraylist

```
List<Character> alphabet = Arrays.asList(a);
```

Make a list to hold the characters that are read:

```
Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<>();
```

Then check whether every character in the sentence is part of the alphabet. Duplicates are not added due to the characteristics of `Set`

```
for (Character c : word.toCharArray()) {
    chars.add(c);
}
```

Then check whether the size of the `Set` is equal to the given alphabet:

```
return (chars.size() == alphabet.size());
```

Comment: Iterating over lists multiple times might be slow though (it's only 26 elements in the worst case but it still can add up) so better use a set. Then you'd not even have to check `chars.contains(c)` but just add it. And you could skip `alphabet.contains(c)` as well and just check `chars.size() == alphabet.size()` at the end to allow for flexible alphabets.

Comment: Very true! I'll make the relevant changes to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
public void checkPanagram() {    
    boolean isPanagram = false;
    String word = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    String a[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
        "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
        "x", "y", "z" };        
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (word.toLowerCase().contains(a[i])) {
            isPanagram = true;
        } else {
            isPanagram = false;
            break;
        }
    }        
    if (isPanagram) System.out.println("Yes, panagram");
    else System.out.println("No, not panagram");
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: if you post code as an answer an explanation of what you changed and why would be nice. This makes it easier for others to understand the meaning of your answer and while writing it you'd reflect as well and maybe spot flaws.

Comment: Ok...I will remember it and do that from next time :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.contains(String)` as every letter in `a` already is a String.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (word.contains(a[i])) {
            count++;
            // } else { break;
        }
    }
```

A remark: better use `String[] a` which is a more regular syntax instead of `String a[]` whose Syntax was added for C/C++ compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

To check equality of a string with a char you could change your code **minimally**

`if ((a[i]).equals(word.charAt(j))` to `if ((a[i]).equals("" + word.charAt(j))`

This gives you an equality check between two strings.

**Alternatively** you can change the line `if ((a[i]).equals(word.charAt(j))` 
to `if ((a[i]).equals(word.substring(j,j+1))`